# C Macro: get smallest type for an integer constant

Tags: c, gcc, casting, macros, c-preprocessor

## Why I need to figure out the smalles type of a literal (Backstory)

I've written a set of macros to create and use fifos. Macros allow for a generic, yet still very fast implementation on all systems with static memory allocation, such as in small embedded systems. The guys over at codereview did not have any major concerns with [my implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179023/fastest-fifo-with-macros-for-use-embedded-devices) either.

The data is put into anonymous struts, all data is accessed by the identifier of that struct. Currently the functions-like macros to create these structs look like this

```
#define _fff_create(_type, _depth, _id)                 \
    struct {uint8_t read; uint8_t write; _type data[_depth];} _id = {0,0,{}}

#define _fff_create_deep(_type, _depth, _id)            \
    struct {uint16_t read; uint16_t write; _type data[_depth];} _id = {0,0,{}}
```

## What I'm looking for

Now I'd like to merge both of these into one macro. To do this I've to figure the minimum required size of `read` and `write` to index `_depth` amount of elements at compile time. Parameters name starting with `_` indicate only a literal or a #define value might be passed, both are known at compile time.

Thus I hope to find a macro `typeof_literal(arg)` which returns `uint8_t` if arg<256 or `uint16_t` else.

## What I've tried

1. GCC 4.9.2. offers a command called [`typeof()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Typeof.html). However when used with any literal it returns an `int` type, which is two byte on my system.
2. Another feature of GCC 4.9.2 is a [compound statement](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). `typeof(({uint8_t u8 = 1; u8;}))` will correctly return `uint8_t`. However I could not figure out a way to put a condition for the type in that block:
3. `typeof(({uint8_t u8 = 1; uint16_t u16 = 1; input ? u8 : u16;}))` always returns `uint16_t` because of the type promotion of the ?: operator
4. `if(...)` can't be used either, as any command will happen in "lower" blocks
5. Macros can't contain `#if`, which make them unusable for this comparison either.

## Can't you just leave it like that?

I realize there might not be a solution to this problem. That's ok too; the current code is just a minor inconvinience. Yet I'd like to know if there's a tricky way around this. A solution to this could open up new possibilities for macros in general. If you are sure that this can't be possible, please explain why.

Comment: This seems like an ideal use case for C++ templates, but I realise your question is not about C++.

Comment: @GregHewgill what would it really help in C if all the constants are of type `int`...

Comment: Names starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation at file-scope. And empty initialiser lists are illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the building block you are looking for is [`__builtin_choose_expr`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fchoose_005fexpr), which is a lot like the ternary operator, but does not convert its result to a common type.  With

```
#define CHOICE(x) __builtin_choose_expr (x, (int) 1, (short) 2)
```

this

```
printf ("%zu %zu\n", sizeof (CHOICE (0)), sizeof (CHOICE (1)));
```

will print

```
2 4
```

as expected.

However, as Greg Hewgill points out, C++ has better facilities for that (but they are still difficult to use).

Comment: On a small microcontroller there are not enough resources to run C++ effectively. Fortunately this solution does work well, the final code is in my answer below. Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 1):

The macro I was looking for can indeed be written with `__builtin_choose_expr` as [Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8316315/florian-weimer) suggested. My solution is attached below, it has been tested and is confirmed working. Use it as you wish!

```
#define typeof_literal(_literal)                                                        \
    typeof(__builtin_choose_expr((_literal)>0,                                          \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)<=UINT8_MAX, (uint8_t) 0,                       \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)<=UINT16_MAX, (uint16_t) 0,                     \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)<=UINT32_MAX, (uint32_t) 0, (uint64_t) 0))),    \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)>=INT8_MIN, (int8_t) 0,                         \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)>=INT16_MIN, (int16_t) 0,                       \
        __builtin_choose_expr((_literal)>=INT32_MIN, (int32_t) 0, (int64_t) 0)))))
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted to 0. This answer is solid. Thank you for providing it. I upvoted your answer from 0 to 1 just now.